# How to change highstock navigator?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

How to change highstock navigator like quarter (year/4):

[image]

Comment: You have to provide some code or a live example. And what do you want to change it for ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vickychijwani/Lee7o707/ See this i want to design bottom like that image

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: You can use alternateGridColor Highcharts option to achieve similar navigator: http://jsfiddle.net/Lee7o707/7/